# Load a custom cell xib from a framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa, dylib

I'm developing a cocoa framework that provides to the hosting app an UINavigationController with a UITableViewController with custom cells in.

I managed to pass UINavigationController with UIViewControllers as root view to the hosting app, using in the navigation controller's didLoad:

```
NSBundle* frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
ContactsListVC *v = [[ContactsListVC alloc]
                 initWithNibName:@"ContactsListVC"
                 bundle:frameworkBundle];

[self addChildViewController: v];
```

But I can't figure out how to load custom cells into the tableview, gives me an error : 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ContactCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the trick.

In the .m of the UITableViewController

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:CONTACTCELL bundle:frameworkBundle];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CONTACTCELL];
    }


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CONTACTCELL forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //other stuff....
    return cell;
    }
```